# Does newrelic REST API V2 be used for Plugins?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to create a new custom Plugin using .NET and I wish to use REST API.

I am trying the new REST API V2 here : https://rpm.newrelic.com/api/explore

there are no specific documentation with regards to Plugins that I could find for REST V2. are Plugins even supported, with this new API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Relics REST API is for getting the metrics that have been reported to New Relic.

For creating a plugin you will want to use the plugin API. Further information about using this can be found on the New Relic doc site.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/working-directly-with-the-plugin-api

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any test Environment where i can test this plugin APIs? I do not want to be sending test information to my production account.

Comment: There isn't a sandbox - but you can signup for a new New Relic account (and get a free Standard account if you signup via any of newrelic.com/offers)